# Changing Default Text of Fivestar Rating Widget

Tags: rating

My fivestar rating says 'no votes yet' when no one has yet voted on the node. How is it possible to change this text to say something else, like 'vote this item'?

I thought this would be a simple problem to solve but wasn't able to find the answer to this anywhere and it's not immediately apparent how this is done when configuring the tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [String overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) make it easy to change that text or any other text in your Drupal site. Install the module, then visit /admin/config/regional/stringoverrides in your site and you can change the text as shown below.

[image]

Then when viewing the vote you'll see:

[image]

Comment: wow, great. Thanks very much for that easy solution.